# Will value ever be 0 after shifting by "x <<= 1" repeatedly?

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am wondering if x will ever reach zero in the following program.

Please consider:

```
int main ()
{
    int x = 1;
    while (x)
      {
        x <<= 1;
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Should the expected behavior of this program be exiting normally or looping forever?

Comment: Trying doesn't work all the time. Especially with undefined behavior.

Comment: use `unsigned int` instead of `int` and it will work.

Comment: As soon as the value gets above the largest `int` value, the operation is undefined. It could return 0, a huge negative value, 42, crash, ...

Answer (score 18):

Neither (or both), it runs in undefined behavior when `x` overflows.

[C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) spec section 6.5.7 says:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
It loops forever with gcc-4.8, but exits normally with all other compilers that I've tried (clang, icc, gcc-4.7).

Comment: @user1519088 there's undefined behavior for you :)

Comment: +1, although for completeness it may be worth pointing out the behaviour for an `unsigned int`, which would probably answer the OP's *intended* question.

Comment: @user1519088: GCC is known to implement "strict signed overflow semantics", which means that cycles that are known to lead to undefined behavior might be replaced with unconditional infinite cycles. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/changes.html

Comment: @user1519088 Here's another very similar example of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682477/gcc-fail-or-undefined-behavior