# Integer overflow concept

Tags: c++, c, integer, overflow

How int overflow works. I mean to ask what would be the final result of an integer value if an overflow happens? I need to understand it on paper. Like I'm given a multiple choice question:

> 11^5 Produces:
>   a. 12
>   b. 14 
>   c. 15 
>   d. 17.

I know the answer is `(b)14`, but want to know why?

Comment: Upvoting for I think it's good that people seek explanations of things.

Comment: Most architectures use a single bit for the _sign_, and fill up with `1`'s.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335784/c-integer-overflow?rq=1)

Comment: MCQ? There's far too many TLAs these days...

Comment: MCQ=> Multiple Choice Q

Comment: So 11^5 is 14? Not with my integer :p First specify the size, signed/unsigned etc.etc.

Comment: `11 ^ 5 --> 14` (decimal) --> `1011 xor 0101 --> 1110` (binary).  No overflow involved.

Answer (score 5):

```
   DecVal   BinVal
    11   -> 1011
XOR 5    -> 0101
           -------
    14   -> 1110
```

fyi, This does not really have anything to do with int overflow.

Comment: Yes here goes the answer. Thanks Sir you got my problem solved.

Comment: @MohsinAli And how this is an overflow problem like you insisted several times?

Comment: look sir I'm new to all these, I thought if it nothing else then it would be overflow problem.

Comment: However Thanks To your effort sir.

Comment: @Alan Stokes Ok sir. What would we be calling it then?

Comment: @MohsinAli It´s a XOR ([bitwise] *exclusive "or"*), a kind of bitwise operation. Essentially a calculation like plus and minus, just different from plus and minus.

Comment: @deviantfan I really confused you sir, and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about wrap-around I'm answering that below. But as is clear from comments, you really tried the C++ expression `11^5`, a bitlevel XOR, and got the answer 14, which has nothing to do with wraparound. The XOR result of each pair of bits is 0 if they're the same value, and 1 if they're different.

---

Now, in the following ^ denotes exponentiation; it's a common notation for that.

11^5 = 161051.

Now consider a situation where 16 bits are used to represent integers, and there's only magnitude, no sign. I.e. a 16-bit unsigned C++ integer type. Then there are 2^16 possible bit patterns, and they are numbered 0 through 2^16 - 1, and represent those numbers.

161051 is larger than the largest possible value of that 16-bit type. If it were 2^16 exactly it would correspond to 0 (called **wrap-around**), if it were 2^16 + 1 it would correspond to 1, and so on. So it corresponds to 161051 - 2^16.

Now if that in turn also was greater than 2^16 - 1 you would repeat the process.

And this produces the remainder of integer division by 2^16.

Essentially it correspond to just *removing* all the bits except the 16 least significant ones.

By the way the result for this example is not any of your choices (a), (b), (c) or (d).

Comment: Appreciate your concern sir, But I run the program on c++ compiler it showed up being (b) 14.

Comment: @Moshin: Aha. You used the expression `11^5` in C++ source code. That does not calculate a power and wrap around. It is a bitlevel XOR operation.

Comment: Sir I need to understand that, Kindly if you could impart the knowledge.

Comment: @MohsinAli Just as side note, the result 14 (with the correct operations) isn´t possible at all, independent from the int size.

Comment: @deviantfan how would it be possible sir?

Comment: @MohsinAli `Sir I need to understand that, Kindly if you could impart the knowledge.` He said that `11^5` in C++ code doesn´t mean `11*11*11*11*11`. C++ is not maths. If you want 11^5 of maths, don´t use `^` of C++

Comment: @MohsinAli `how would it be possible sir?` It is *not* possible. `11^5 % 2^x = 14` is not solvable with natural numbers x.

Comment: @deviantfan I'm not doing math here sir. I'm trying to get the ways of c++.

Comment: @AlanStokes I´m assuming that OP means exponentiation.

Comment: If the result goes out of the range of integer then is there any kind of truncating happens?

Comment: @deviantfan It's not merely possible, it's required. `^` in C++ denotes bitwise xor. This is clearer in binary. 1011 ^ 0101 = 1110. In  decimal, 11^5 = 14.

Comment: @deviantfan Why? Question is tagged C++.

Comment: @AlanStokes Well, why... good question. Maybe because he´s mentioning overflows. Mohsin Ali: Please clarify.

Comment: Right sir. I'm dealing with overflowing problem. How does that go in c++?