# Why does my program go wrong in big numbers

Tags: c, for-loop, fibonacci

I was trying to make a program that prompts a user for a int value which uses is as the nth of the Fibonacci sequence.

This has goes all well for me until if you input 48. The  Fibonacci output shows the last term a negative number, am I doing something wrong?

Open to criticism, I accept some pointers to study on more.

```
int i,Nth,Num1=0,Num2=1,Num3;
Num3=Num1+Num2;
printf("Enter Fibonacci Sequence terms limit: ");
scanf("%d",&Nth);
printf("Fibonacci Sequence: %d, %d",Num1,Num2);
for(i=3;i<=Nth;++i){
    printf(", %d",Num3);
    Num1=Num2;
    Num2=Num3;
    Num3=Num1+Num2;
};
```

This is the output when entering 48:

```
Fibonacci Sequence: 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 
1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 
514229, 832040, 1346269, 2178309, 3524578, 5702887, 9227465, 14930352, 24157817, 
39088169, 63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 
1836311903, -1323752223
```

Comment: The question to ask yourself is: how many bytes are used to define an `int`, and what's the maximum value that can be represented with that number of bytes?

Comment: but is there a library to give me access to a big data type or do i just go to unsigned long long

Comment: You can start by going to a larger int type (unsigned long long or uint64_t), but you'll eventually hit a limit with that type which may or may not be acceptable. If you need much larger precision, google for `"big integer library in c"`

Comment: @Kryspin Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12335784/16835308).

Comment: @Kryspin: The [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/) library may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Fibonacci output shows the last term a negative number, am I doing something wrong?

Yes, you are. You have a signed integer overflow in your code. This is undefined behaviour, which means that anything can happen (including a *"seemingly"* working code).

> this goes all well for me until if you input 48.

You can check the maximum value of an integer on your platform using `INT_MAX`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h> // You have to include this header

int main(void)
{
    printf("INT_MAX = %d\n", INT_MAX);
}
```

Output:

```text
INT_MAX = 2147483647
```

Which is smaller than `fib(47) = 2971215073`.

---

One solution is to use `long` instead of `int`. This will solve your problem, unless you want very huge numbers. In this case, you would want to use a dedicated library.

Comment: _"One solution is to use long instead of int"_:  not on all platforms, on my platform `int` and `long` have the same size. Using `long long int` or just ``long long  rather than `long` increases your chance.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You can take a look at your compiler's documentation and see what all integer sizes are up to.

Answer (score 2):

You've reached integer's maxmimum:

`1836311903 + 1134903170 = 2,971,215,073`
`32 bit Integer Maximum = 2,147,483,647`

You should try different data types to get more values.
More about data types in C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Answer (score -2):

int can express up to 1836311903.

if you want to show 48th,

you should consider using long

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).