# for(++i;++i;++i) the second argument is < or <=?

Tags: c, for-loop

In this for loop statement

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  static int i; 
  for(++i;++i;++i) { 
    printf("%d ",i); 

    if(i==4) 
       break; 
 } 
 return 0; 

}
```

Variable `i` is at first 0. The arguments in the for-loop at 1st round are 
  **1st ++i:** `i = 0 + 1 = 1` 
 **2nd ++i:** `i=1+1=2` 
 So, in first loop I have this `for(i=1; i<2; ++i);`  or `for(i=1; i<=2; ++i);`?
**EDIT** I found this example online in a test about C. I run this (inside the for-loop , I have a break point so after some loops it breaks) but I was just guessing the behavior of that so I asked it here to be sure. I am learning now C so stupid questions exists for me. Its better to ask, than not.

Comment: You have neither `<` nor `<=` in your code, so why would you expect it to behave like either?

Comment: @nhahtdh: at some point, `i` will overflow, and `++i` will be `0`, and the loop will break

Comment: Why do you want to torture yourself with dire code like this?

Comment: Why don't you run it and enlighten us with your findings?

Comment: You have neither: what you have is (implicitly) `++i != 0`. Since your `i` is incrementing, this will hit undefined behavior when it increments past `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Would this even compile? The second condition in a for-loop is of bool type. `++i` IS NOT a bool type.

Comment: @Elias or not. Undefined behaviour is undefined. See here for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682477/why-does-integer-overflow-on-x86-with-gcc-cause-an-infinite-loop. There is no integer overflow in C.

Comment: I run it but I just guess the result!! I wanted to be sure about the behavior of this  @OliCharlesworth

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Fair point... bitten by undefined behaviour once more...

Comment: @waka, remember that this is C, C does not have a type system

Comment: When I first used the for-loop I saw examples with `<` and `<=` etc.. I didn't realize that the 2nd argument was just a condition. @OliCharlesworth

Comment: @Jefffrey: Thanks. I totally forgot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second argument it is actually `++i!=0`, The loop is interpreted as

```
for(++i;++i!=0;++i)
```

If you start with a positive `i` or `0`, it will be an infinite loop and will invoke undefined behavior when `i` reaches `INT_MAX`.

If `i` was `-Ve` initially the loop may stop at a defined run.

EDIT: As you changed your question, Your code will not crash, but you can clearly understand the dry-run by replacing the second `++i` with `++i!=0`.

So the 1st iteration becomes:

```
(i=1;2!=0;++i/*this will execute later*/)
```

2nd iteration becomes:

```
i=3 //this is from the 1st iteration last part.
(/*initialization is done 1st time only*/;4!=0;++i/*again, this will execute after this iteration*/)
```

Answer (score 2):

It will print `2 4`.

Before the for loop, i will be 0. It hasn't been assigned anything yet, and `static` variables are guaranteed to be zero initialized before they are first used.

It will execute the first `++i` in the for loop, since that expression is evaluated once at the beginning of the loop. `i` will be `1`.

It will execute the second ++i, because that is evaluated BEFORE every loop to see if it should run an iteration of the loop. `i` will be `2`.

It will run the loop body. This will print `2`.

The `if` condition won't be true so it won't `break`.

It will execute the third `++i` in the for loop statement, since it evaluates that AFTER every iteration. `i` will be `3`.

It will execute the second `++i` again, since it needs to see if it needs to run another loop. It will be nonzero, so it will run another loop. `i` will be 4.

It will print `4`.

The `if` condition will be true, it will `break` out of the loop.

However, it is a nonsense way to do it. This is a more appropriate way to do that:

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i <= 4; i += 2)
    printf("%d ", i);
```

or better yet:

```
printf("2 4 ");
```

Comment: I know that this is very stupid way to do this. I just found the example in an online test about C and I was curious about that.

Comment: Hopefully my walk-through helps you understand what those three things are in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
   static int i;
```

While the C standard guarantees that variables with static storage duration are initialized to 0, you should not abuse that. Always initialize your variables, either at the line where they are declared or in runtime. So change this to `static int i=0;`

The first ++i is indeed equivalent to having `i=1` there. Esentially your loop does this:

```
for(i=1; loop_until_program_crash; i++)
```

If you have a `break` inside the loop, then the loop is likely poorly written. If you know in advance when the loop should end, then that condition should be inside the for loop condition. If you don't know in advance, then use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :

```
for(i=1; i<=2; ++i);
static int i=0;
for(++i;++i<=2;++i)
{
      printf("4rth :%d\n",i);
}
```

see : http://ideone.com/TGLYlL