# g++ optimization breaks for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, optimization, nested-loops

A few days ago, I encountered what I believe to be a bug in g++ 5.3 concerning the nesting of for loops at higher `-OX` optimization levels. (Been experiencing it specifically for `-O2` and `-O3`). The issue is that if you have two nested for loops, that have some internal sum to keep track of total iterations, once this sum exceeds its maximum value it prevents the outer loop from terminating. The smallest code set that I have been able to replicate this with is:

```
int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    //                 Value of 100 million. (2047483648 less than int32 max.)
    int maxInner = 100000000;

    int maxOuter = 30;

    // 100million * 30 = 3 billion. (Larger than int32 max)

    for(int i = 0; i < maxOuter; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxInner; ++j)
        {
            ++sum;
        }
        std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

When this is compiled using `g++ -o run.me main.cpp` it runs just as expected outputting:

```
i = 0 sum = 100000000
i = 1 sum = 200000000
i = 2 sum = 300000000
i = 3 sum = 400000000
i = 4 sum = 500000000
i = 5 sum = 600000000
i = 6 sum = 700000000
i = 7 sum = 800000000
i = 8 sum = 900000000
i = 9 sum = 1000000000
i = 10 sum = 1100000000
i = 11 sum = 1200000000
i = 12 sum = 1300000000
i = 13 sum = 1400000000
i = 14 sum = 1500000000
i = 15 sum = 1600000000
i = 16 sum = 1700000000
i = 17 sum = 1800000000
i = 18 sum = 1900000000
i = 19 sum = 2000000000
i = 20 sum = 2100000000
i = 21 sum = -2094967296
i = 22 sum = -1994967296
i = 23 sum = -1894967296
i = 24 sum = -1794967296
i = 25 sum = -1694967296
i = 26 sum = -1594967296
i = 27 sum = -1494967296
i = 28 sum = -1394967296
i = 29 sum = -1294967296
```

However, when this is compiled using `g++ -O2 -o run.me main.cpp`, the outer loop fails to terminate. (This only occurs when `maxInner * maxOuter > 2^31`) While sum continually overflows, it shouldn't in any way affect the other variables. I have also tested this on Ideone.com with the test case demonstrated here: https://ideone.com/5MI5Jb

My question is thus twofold.

1. **How is it possible for the value of sum to in some way effect the system? No decisions are based upon its value, it is merely utilized for the purposes of a counter and the `std::cout` statement.**
2. **What could possibly be causing the dramatically different outcomes at different optimization levels?**

*Thank you greatly in advance for taking the time to read and consider my question.*

*Note: This question differs from existing questions such as: [Why does integer overflow on x86 with GCC cause an infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682477/why-does-integer-overflow-on-x86-with-gcc-cause-an-infinite-loop) because the issue with that problem was an overflow for the sentinal variable. However, both sentinal variables in this question `i` and `j` never exceed the value of 100m let alone 2^31.*

Comment: When you write [*Undefined Behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), your program can do **anything**. People find "compiler bugs" all the time by turning on optimisations. I've yet to see a case where their code was not broken.

Comment: [Signed integer overflow triggers undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/464709). You're lucky to get away with only an infinite loop -- dragons could be coming out of your nose as we speak.

Comment: In this particular case, it seems the compiler is spotting that the end condition can't possibly be reached (since to do so would require something illegal), so doesn't even bother checking it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi While it is true that overflows are undefined its my understanding that the undefined behaviour was contained to that particular integer, why does this differ with the compiler flags?

Comment: You can't "contain" Undefined Behaviour. Even in time - if you perform some illegal action at some point in your code, even everything that happens before you get anywhere near that action is undefined.

Comment: Change `sum` to be `unsigned int` and everything is fine and dandy. https://ideone.com/cr1sGC

Comment: @BoBTFish How does it find that though (That the loop will never reach the end)? The value of `sum` is the only one that overflows, and it has nothing to do with checking the end conditions. The loop is perfectly capable of executing normally.

Comment: @Chris, that's why it's called *undefined behavior*. What seems logical to us humans doesn't matter much to the optimizer, which is quite a complicated beast.

Comment: @ChrisBritt The compiler sees (I'm guessing) that to hit the termination condition, it would have to perform an illegal addition. It may assume such an addition does not occur, therefore the termination condition does not occur. Therefore it can skip the check.

Comment: Are unsigned integers guaranteed to be safe from overflow undefined behavior? In my original application that I discovered this the overflow itself is not to detrimental, but the crashing of the loop has been a major issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does integer overflow on x86 with GCC cause an infinite loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682477/why-does-integer-overflow-on-x86-with-gcc-cause-an-infinite-loop)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The difference is that the overflow character was also the termination character in that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answers

As @hvd pointed out, the problem is in your invalid code, not in the compiler.

During your program execution, the `sum` value overflows `int` range. Since `int` is by default `signed` and overflow of `signed` values causes undefined behavior* in C, the compiler is free to do anything. As someone noted somewhere, dragons could be flying out of your nose. The result is just undefined.

The difference `-O2` causes is in testing the end condition. When the compiler optimizes your loop, it realizes that it can optimize away the inner loop, making it

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < maxOuter; i++) {
    sum += maxInner;
    std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

and it may go further, transforming it to

```
int i = 0;
for(int sum = 0; sum < (maxInner * maxOuter); sum += maxInner) {
    i++;
    std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

*To be honest, I don't really know what it **does**, the point is, it **can** do just this. Or anything else, remember the dragons, your program causes **undefined** behavior.*

Suddenly, your `sum` variable is used in the loop end condition. *Note that for defined behavior, these optimizations are perfectly valid. If your `sum` was `unsigned` (and your `maxInner` and `maxOuter`), the `(maxInner * maxOuter)` value (which would also be `unsigned`) would be reached after `maxOuter` loops, because `unsigned` operations are defined** to overflow as expected.*

Now since we're in the `signed` domain, the compiler is for one free to assume, that at all times `sum < (maxInner * maxOuter)`, just because the latter overflows, and therefore is not defined. So the optimizing compiler can end up with something like

```
int i = 0;
for(int sum = 0;/* nothing here evaluates to true */; sum += maxInner) {
    i++;
    std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
}
```

which looks like observed behavior.

***: According to the [C11 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.5 Expressions:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior is undefined.

****: According to the [C11 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), Annex H, H.2.2:

> C’s unsigned integer types are ‘‘modulo’’ in the LIA−1 sense in that overflows or out-of-bounds results silently wrap.

---

I did some research on the topic. I compiled the code above with `gcc` and `g++` (version 5.3.0 on Manjaro) and got some pretty interesting things of it.

### Description

To successfully compile it with `gcc` (C compiler, that is), I have replaced

```
#include <iostream>
...
std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
```

with

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
printf("i = %d sum = %d\n", i, sum);
```

and wrapped this replacement with `#ifndef ORIG`, so I could have both versions. Then I ran 8 compilations: {`gcc`,`g++`} x {`-O2`, `""`} x {`-DORIG=1`,`""`}. This yields following results:

### Results

1. `gcc`, `-O2`, `-DORIG=1`: Won't compile, missing `<iostream>`. *Not surprising*.
2. `gcc`, `-O2`, `""`: Produces compiler warning and behaves "normally". A look in the assembly shows that the inner loop is optimized out (`j` being incremented by 100000000) and the outer loop variable is compared with hardcoded value -1294967296. *So, GCC **can** detect this and do some clever things while the program is working expectably. More importantly, warning is emitted to warn user about undefined behavior.*
3. `gcc`, `""`, `-DORIG=1`: Won't compile, missing `<iostream>`. *Not surprising.*
4. `gcc`, `""`, `""`: Compiles without warning. No optimizations, program runs as expected.
5. `g++`, `-O2`, `-DORIG=1`: Compiles without warning, runs in endless loop. This is OP's original code running. *C++ assembly is tough to follow for me. Addition of 100000000 is there though.*
6. `g++`, `-O2`, `""`: Compiles **with** warning. It is enough to change how the output is printed to change compiler warning emiting. Runs "normally". *By the assembly, AFAIK the inner loop gets optimized out. At least there is again comparison against -1294967296 and incrementation by 100000000.*
7. `g++`, `""`, `-DORIG=1`: Compiles without warning. No optimization, runs "normally".
8. `g++`, `""`, `""`: dtto

The most interesting part for me was to find out the difference upon change of printing. Actually from all the combinations, only the one used by OP produces endless-loop program, the others fail to compile, do not optimize or optimize with warning and preserve sanity.

### Code

Follows example build command and my full code

```
$ gcc -x c -Wall -Wextra -O2 -DORIG=1 -o gcc_opt_orig  main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#ifdef ORIG
#include <iostream>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    //                 Value of 100 million. (2047483648 less than int32 max.)
    int maxInner = 100000000;

    int maxOuter = 30;

    // 100million * 30 = 3 billion. (Larger than int32 max)

    for(int i = 0; i < maxOuter; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < maxInner; ++j)
        {
            ++sum;
        }
#ifdef ORIG
        std::cout<<"i = "<<i<<" sum = "<<sum<<std::endl;
#else
        printf("i = %d sum = %d\n", i, sum);
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perhaps interesting commentary, but it doesn't answer either of the two explicit questions the OP asked, nor does it try to. Given that the OP has nonetheless for some reason decided to accept your post as the correct answer, nothing is likely to happen to it, but just as a heads up, normally posts like these get deleted. Putting your tests as extra commentary in a post that also manages to answer the question would be wholly appropriate though.

Comment: @hvd Thanks for the notice. I realized that the extent of the text is too big for a comment, so I made it an answer, though I know it does not technically answer OP's question (this has been done well enough before me). I am frankly surprised by the answer being accepted. Is there any reasonable way to post a "comment" (like this answer) in the magnitude of this answer?

Comment: Or would answering the questions (more or less replicating others' answers) in the beginning be appropriate?

Comment: Interesting note: [with `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`, g++ still warns about the undefined behaviour](https://godbolt.org/g/FbRHUN).  Note that `std::endl` forces a flush even if the stream is fully buffered, instead of line buffered, so there is more going on in the loop with `endl`.  IDK why the code is so much more complicated, though.  There's even a call to a virtual function (the `call rax`), and some crap about `std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char)`.

Comment: Optimizing away a loop into `+= 100000000` isn't called loop unrolling.  I'm not sure what the technical term for it is, but [loop unrolling has a specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling#A_simple_manual_example_in_C), and this isn't it.  RE: how to make this a better answer: copy gcc's warning into a new first paragraph, and say it's from the signed overflow.  It leads to gcc making unexpected assumptions about what the loop will do.  Maybe also say "see the other answers" if you don't want to go in depth about that issue, since it is covered nicely by others.

Comment: @HonzaRemeš Not on site, unfortunately. Some users put it on an external site and link to it in a comment. That's fine, but so is answering the question in addition to the commentary. If you can come up with the answer yourself, you can include that and perhaps briefly mention if that part is the same as an existing answer. Otherwise, just make sure to give proper attribution for anything that isn't your own. I've seen the basic structure "(user) answered that (answer). (user) is correct, but I want to add to that: (commentary)" used, and I think it's enough to make it an answer.

Comment: @hvd & Peter Cordes: Thank you both for comments and suggestions. I've edited the answer to make it better.

Comment: Good edit, the first bit explains the problem nicely.  Interesting analysis of what it might be transforming the loop into, with sum as part of the loop-termination condition.  The compiler transformations that produce this effect were probably not designed to produce this effect.  It's just a side effect of how they work to produce useful optimizations in other cases.  At least, I hope they produce a useful effect in some cases!

Answer (score 12):

This is an optimisation that's perfectly valid for correct code. Your code isn't correct.

What GCC sees is that the only way the loop exit condition `i >= maxOuter` could ever be reached is if you have signed integer overflow during earlier loop iterations in your calculation of `sum`. The compiler assumes there isn't signed integer overflow, because signed integer overflow isn't allowed in standard C. Therefore, `i < maxOuter` can be optimised to just `true`.

This is controlled by the `-faggressive-loop-optimizations` flag. You should be able to get the behaviour you expect by adding `-fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations` to your command line arguments. But better would be making sure your code is valid. Use unsigned integer types to get guaranteed valid wraparound behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour, since the int sum overflows. You say "this shouldn't in any way affect the other variables". Wrong. Once you have undefined behaviour, all odds are off. Anything can happen.

gcc is (in)famous for optimisations that assume there is no undefined behaviour and do let's say interesting things if undefined behaviour happens.

Solution: Don't do it.