# How does an integer value end up negative when positively incrementing?

Tags: c++

I'm just write this code but I don't know how it works.

Why the value of `k` will be negative? How?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k=1,j=0;
    while(k>j)
    {
        j=k;
        k++;
    }
    cout<<j<<"\n"<<k;
}
```

it shows the range of an integer

Comment: `#include<iostream>
using namespace std;` is not C.  Please don't add the C tag.

Comment: signed overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c

Comment: [**Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @NathanOliver code syntax is C++ but its basically C language that is why i tag bot c and c++

Comment: @UZAIR69 If you can't compile it in a C compiler, which you can't, then it is not C code.  C and C++ share a lot of the same syntax so we care on what language the code is compiled against, not how it looks.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sorry ! im a beginner programm , i just only learn coding.im not a professional programmer

Answer (score 6):

`int` has a limited range. At some time, `k++` overflows this limit. After that point, the behavior is undefined and anything can happen.

If the compiler is very conservative, then it will simply overflow to negative values (particularly in the near-ubiquitous case where `int` is 2's complement), but that is not guaranteed. In that case, the `while` loop will terminate.

Look at what gcc does with and without optimization. Both behaviors are legal according the standard, as signed overflow behavior is undefined.

[With optimization](https://godbolt.org/z/nFNAnV) (infinite loop):

```
main:
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
```

[Without optimization](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Crqt0ZtvLaGb7TXb):
Prints:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

Again, anything can happen, not only the above two behaviors. Signed overflow is undefined.

Comment: @Bathsheba Good point, as signed-magnitude (or 1's complement) may do something different in case of an overflow. Also, overflow might trap, which I forgot to mention.

Comment: Signed magnitude and 1's complement tend to clamp. Although I am revealing my age here...

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of your code is *undefined* due to the overflow of a signed integral type.

There is no defined way by which `k` can become negative. Because of that, a good compiler (optimising gcc for example) may well compile `while(k > j)` to, effectively, `while(true)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 It would be UB if the user did it.  It's legal for the compiler to do so as the condition never needs to be checked.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Thanks Nathan: I was in the middle of checking this.

Comment: As we are in UB world, (any, not only "good") compilers may do anything. So I dislike the wording. And I mean that `while(true);` is also UB, and allow compilers to do anything too.

Comment: @Jarod42: I'll bung in an "effectively".

Comment: And yes, some compilers will mark the control path as unreachable which means the entire program gets compiled to `int main(){}` in this case.

Comment: @Bathsheba [Or something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36626810/560648)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will keep on incrementing the variable `k` because the condition `k > j` is true. At some point `k` will get equal to the maximum `int` value supported on your system. When you do `k++` in the next loop, the result is not representable as an `int`. This is called **integer overflow** and according to the standard, the code has **undefined behavior**. As it is undefined behavior we can't say what will happen in general - it is system specific.

On many system the result of incrementing the maximum `int`value will result in the minimum `int` value. On such systems your code is equivalent to the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int j = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  int k = j + 1;
  std::cout << j << std::endl << k << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

On my system the output is:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
```

But **do not** expect this to hold for all systems. On other systems the program may crash, or enter an endless loop or do whatever... it is undefined by the standard.

A better way to write the code so that it will work on all systems is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  int j = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
  int k = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  std::cout << j << std::endl << k << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hum. Since the behaviour is undefined, the code the OP presents is equivalent to *any* code.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, k is always one greater than j at the time of the test, until it exceeds the maximum value that can be represented by an int. Then (in your case, as evidenced by your question -- it is indeed not defined by the standard) it rolls over to the other end of the range: the maximum negative value.

Comment: how it rolls over to the other end of the range ?

Comment: "how"? In your case, by incrementing it. See the links given in the comments to the OP for more info.

Answer (score -1):

the while goes on until j is 2147483647

2147483647 +1 = -2147483648

the integer 32bit overflows and become negative, stopping the while.

Comment: It's not that helpful: it's only one possibility (albeit a likely one on the current crop of desktop PCs).

Comment: Uhm... I'm sure that's what happened in OP case, also I never seen a compiler do it a different way. Rollover can be very beneficial especially in microcontrollers where abusing side effects can save instructions. Still, I never tried compiling with very aggressive settings. I think O2 should pretty much garantuee this result.